# I have a ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Crypto'

Tags: python

Please need help

When I try to run myfile.py it says, ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Crypto' ,but I already have the path for 'conda' and 'anaconda3' in my environment variables, I also have uninstalled and reinstalled pycryptodome yet it still says ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Crypto'.

> This is what I used in myfile.py

```
from Crypto import Random                                     
from Crypto.Cipher import AES
import builtins
import os
import os.path
from os import listdir
from os.path import isfile, join
import time
```

also had these packages installed:

```
alabaster                          0.7.12
anaconda-client                    1.7.2
anaconda-navigator                 1.9.12
anaconda-project                   0.8.3
argh                               0.26.2
asn1crypto                         1.3.0
astroid                            2.4.2
astropy                            4.0.1.post1
atomicwrites                       1.4.0
attrs                              19.3.0
autopep8                           1.5.3
Babel                              2.8.0
backcall                           0.2.0
backports.functools-lru-cache      1.6.1
backports.shutil-get-terminal-size 1.0.0
backports.tempfile                 1.0
backports.weakref                  1.0.post1
bcrypt                             3.1.7
beautifulsoup4                     4.9.1
bitarray                           1.4.0
bkcharts                           0.2
bleach                             3.1.5
bokeh                              2.1.1
boto                               2.49.0
Bottleneck                         1.3.2
brotlipy                           0.7.0
certifi                            2020.6.20
cffi                               1.14.0
chardet                            3.0.4
click                              7.1.2
cloudpickle                        1.5.0
clyent                             1.2.2
colorama                           0.4.3
comtypes                           1.1.7
conda                              4.8.3
conda-build                        3.18.11
conda-package-handling             1.7.0
conda-verify                       3.4.2
contextlib2                        0.6.0.post1
cryptography                       2.9.2
cycler                             0.10.0
Cython                             0.29.21
cytoolz                            0.10.1
dask                               2.20.0
decorator                          4.4.2
defusedxml                         0.6.0
diff-match-patch                   20200713
distributed                        2.20.0
docutils                           0.16
entrypoints                        0.3
et-xmlfile                         1.0.1
fastcache                          1.1.0
filelock                           3.0.12
flake8                             3.8.3
Flask                              1.1.2
fsspec                             0.7.4
future                             0.18.2
gevent                             20.6.2
glob2                              0.7
gmpy2                              2.0.8
greenlet                           0.4.16
h5py                               2.10.0
HeapDict                           1.0.1
html5lib                           1.1
idna                               2.10
imageio                            2.9.0
imagesize                          1.2.0
importlib-metadata                 1.7.0
intervaltree                       3.0.2
ipykernel                          5.3.2
ipython                            7.16.1
ipython-genutils                   0.2.0
ipywidgets                         7.5.1
isort                              4.3.21
itsdangerous                       1.1.0
jdcal                              1.4.1
jedi                               0.17.1
Jinja2                             2.11.2
joblib                             0.16.0
json5                              0.9.5
jsonschema                         3.2.0
jupyter                            1.0.0
jupyter-client                     6.1.6
jupyter-console                    6.1.0
jupyter-core                       4.6.3
jupyterlab                         2.1.5
jupyterlab-server                  1.2.0
keyring                            21.2.1
kiwisolver                         1.2.0
lazy-object-proxy                  1.4.3
libarchive-c                       2.9
llvmlite                           0.33.0+1.g022ab0f
locket                             0.2.0
lxml                               4.5.2
MarkupSafe                         1.1.1
matplotlib                         3.2.2
mccabe                             0.6.1
menuinst                           1.4.16
mistune                            0.8.4
mkl-fft                            1.1.0
mkl-random                         1.1.1
mkl-service                        2.3.0
mock                               4.0.2
more-itertools                     8.4.0
mpmath                             1.1.0
msgpack                            1.0.0
multipledispatch                   0.6.0
navigator-updater                  0.2.1
nbconvert                          5.6.1
nbformat                           5.0.7
networkx                           2.4
nltk                               3.5
nose                               1.3.7
notebook                           6.0.3
numba                              0.50.1
numexpr                            2.7.1
numpy                              1.18.5
numpydoc                           1.1.0
olefile                            0.46
openpyxl                           3.0.4
packaging                          20.4
pandas                             1.0.5
pandocfilters                      1.4.2
paramiko                           2.7.1
parso                              0.7.0
partd                              1.1.0
path                               13.1.0
pathlib2                           2.3.5
pathtools                          0.1.2
patsy                              0.5.1
pep8                               1.7.1
pexpect                            4.8.0
pickleshare                        0.7.5
Pillow                             7.2.0
pip                                20.1.1
pkginfo                            1.5.0.1
pluggy                             0.13.1
ply                                3.11
prometheus-client                  0.8.0
prompt-toolkit                     3.0.5
psutil                             5.7.0
py                                 1.9.0
pycodestyle                        2.6.0
pycosat                            0.6.3
pycparser                          2.20
pycryptodomex                      3.9.9
pycurl                             7.43.0.5
pydocstyle                         5.0.2
pyflakes                           2.2.0
Pygments                           2.6.1
pylint                             2.5.3
PyNaCl                             1.4.0
pyodbc                             4.0.0-unsupported
pyOpenSSL                          19.1.0
pyparsing                          2.4.7
pyreadline                         2.1
pyrsistent                         0.16.0
PySocks                            1.7.1
pytest                             5.4.3
python-dateutil                    2.8.1
python-jsonrpc-server              0.3.4
python-language-server             0.34.1
pytz                               2020.1
PyWavelets                         1.1.1
pywin32                            227
pywin32-ctypes                     0.2.0
pywinpty                           0.5.7
PyYAML                             5.3.1
pyzmq                              19.0.1
QDarkStyle                         2.8.1
QtAwesome                          0.7.2
qtconsole                          4.7.5
QtPy                               1.9.0
regex                              2020.6.8
requests                           2.24.0
rope                               0.17.0
Rtree                              0.9.4
ruamel-yaml                        0.15.87
scikit-image                       0.16.2
scikit-learn                       0.23.1
scipy                              1.5.0
seaborn                            0.10.1
Send2Trash                         1.5.0
setuptools                         49.2.0.post20200714
simplegeneric                      0.8.1
singledispatch                     3.4.0.3
sip                                4.19.13
six                                1.15.0
snowballstemmer                    2.0.0
sortedcollections                  1.2.1
sortedcontainers                   2.2.2
soupsieve                          2.0.1
Sphinx                             3.1.2
sphinxcontrib-applehelp            1.0.2
sphinxcontrib-devhelp              1.0.2
sphinxcontrib-htmlhelp             1.0.3
sphinxcontrib-jsmath               1.0.1
sphinxcontrib-qthelp               1.0.3
sphinxcontrib-serializinghtml      1.1.4
sphinxcontrib-websupport           1.2.3
spyder                             4.1.4
spyder-kernels                     1.9.2
SQLAlchemy                         1.3.18
statsmodels                        0.11.1
sympy                              1.6.1
tables                             3.6.1
tblib                              1.6.0
terminado                          0.8.3
testpath                           0.4.4
threadpoolctl                      2.1.0
toml                               0.10.1
toolz                              0.10.0
tornado                            6.0.4
tqdm                               4.47.0
traitlets                          4.3.3
typing-extensions                  3.7.4.2
ujson                              1.35
unicodecsv                         0.14.1
urllib3                            1.25.9
watchdog                           0.10.3
wcwidth                            0.2.5
webencodings                       0.5.1
Werkzeug                           1.0.1
wheel                              0.34.2
widgetsnbextension                 3.5.1
win-inet-pton                      1.1.0
win-unicode-console                0.5
wincertstore                       0.2
wrapt                              1.11.2
xlrd                               1.2.0
XlsxWriter                         1.2.9
xlwings                            0.19.5
xlwt                               1.3.0
xmltodict                          0.12.0
yapf                               0.30.0
zict                               2.0.0
zipp                               3.1.0
zope.event                         4.4
zope.interface                     4.7.1
```

Comment: Can you check your PYTHONPATH?

Comment: here: C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\python.exe, 
          C:\Users\Admin\anaconda3\python.exe

Comment: Since you're using conda, make sure you are installing Crypto into the environment that you are also coding in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally Worked, I tried installing `pycryptodome` using the command `py -m pip install pycryptodome` instead of `pip install pycryptodome`. This happens because `py` is the Python launcher.

Answer (score 0):

Your package list seems to be missing the required library (`pyCrypto`).

Not too familiar with conda, but try:

```
$ conda install pyCrypto
```

Here is an example with just python:

```
root@47cbabc35dca:/# python
Python 3.9.0 (default, Nov 18 2020, 13:28:38)
[GCC 8.3.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from Crypto import Random
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Crypto'
>>>
root@47cbabc35dca:/# python -m pip install pyCrypto
Collecting pyCrypto
  Downloading pycrypto-2.6.1.tar.gz (446 kB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 446 kB 3.0 MB/s
Building wheels for collected packages: pyCrypto
  Building wheel for pyCrypto (setup.py) ... done
  Created wheel for pyCrypto: filename=pycrypto-2.6.1-cp39-cp39-linux_x86_64.whl size=521774 sha256=efc58b4ee8a1b8404b06b4d5aa75e51ebe90e6eec90e68f00b1e805582fcbc74
  Stored in directory: /root/.cache/pip/wheels/9d/29/32/8b8f22481bec8b0fbe7087927336ec167faff2ed9db849448f
Successfully built pyCrypto
Installing collected packages: pyCrypto
Successfully installed pyCrypto-2.6.1
root@47cbabc35dca:/# python
Python 3.9.0 (default, Nov 18 2020, 13:28:38)
[GCC 8.3.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from Crypto import Random
>>>
```